# (ROLE_ADMIN ROLE_USER) Spring Security Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

it is the first time i use **Spring Security** with **Spring WebFlow**. I have two users (admin; user) each one have her only space.

The structure of my project is like this :

[image]

The Folder "**compte**" for User contain :

- file.xhtml
- compte-flow.xml

The Folder "**compteAdmin**" for Admin contain :

- file.xhtml
- compteAdmin-flow.xml

The Folder "**main**" contain :

- fileAuthentication.xhtml
- main-flow.xml

Configuration of **main-flow.xml** is :

```
<view-state id="authentification" view="authentification.xhtml" model="user">
    <transition on="valider" to="authentifierUser" />

</view-state>

<action-state id="authentifierUser">
    <evaluate
        expression="userAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(user)" />
    <transition on="yes" to="finish" />
    <transition on="no" to="authentification" />
</action-state>

<end-state id="finish" view="externalRedirect:compteAdmin" />
```

Configuration of **security-config.xml** is :

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/main" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/main/compteAdmin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/main/compte" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/app/main" default-target-url="/app/main"/>

    <security:logout logout-url="/app/logout"
        logout-success-url="/app/main" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In this case only Admin had acces to her space. So how to configure **main-flow.xml** in order to let User also access to her space.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any one know how to solve this issue ??